# Removing speed using `srm` and the Gutmann method is too low

Tags: debian, ubuntu, security, deleted-files

I need to delete some files using Gutmann method. Deleting files using 
`srm -rvz` took for me more than 16 hours and after that I canceled it.

After that I do a test: I tried to delete a 5GB file using `wipe`. It took ~8hours for 2 passes and ETA was 6days. In Windows using eraser and Gutmann method (same method as `wipe` uses) it took less than one hour for a 2GB file.

Why the speed is soo low? The write/read speed is almost the same for both OS.

Answer (score 2):

The Gutmann method was published in 1996. Since then, Peter Gutmann himself has said:

[https://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/~pgut001/pubs/secure_del.html#Epilogue](https://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/%7Epgut001/pubs/secure_del.html#Epilogue)

> In the time since this paper was published, some people have treated the 35-pass overwrite technique described in it more as a kind of voodoo incantation to banish evil spirits than the result of a technical analysis of drive encoding techniques. As a result, they advocate applying the voodoo to PRML and EPRML drives even though it will have no more effect than a simple scrubbing with random data.
>
> In fact performing the full 35-pass overwrite is pointless for any drive since it targets a blend of scenarios involving all types of (normally-used) encoding technology, which covers everything back to 30+-year-old MFM methods (if you don't understand that statement, re-read the paper). If you're using a drive which uses encoding technology X, you only need to perform the passes specific to X, and you never need to perform all 35 passes.
>
> For any modern PRML/EPRML drive, a few passes of random scrubbing is the best you can do. As the paper says, "A good scrubbing with random data will do about as well as can be expected". This was true in 1996, and is still true now.

Maybe the Windows eraser optimizes things and omits the passes it deems irrelevant?

Also, it looks like `srm` is developed using the principle of "out of abundance of caution, do everything possible". Maybe the use of `O_SYNC` mode, the `fsync()` calls and other things `srm` does to try and ensure to ensure all disk caches get flushed are causing the slowdown.